# A map between Banach spaces is continuous - counterexample

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Today the following question came up ([A map between Banach spaces is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498261/a-map-between-banach-spaces-is-continuous)):

> I'm trying to prove this statement:
>
> Let $(X_0, \| \cdot \|_{X_0})$ and $(X_1, \|\cdot \|_{X_1})$ be Banach spaces and $(Y_0, \| \cdot \|_{Y_0})$ and $(Y_1, \|\cdot \|_{Y_1})$ normed spaces so that $X_0$ is a vector subspace of $Y_0$ and $X_1$ is a vector subspace of $Y_1$.
>
> Further assume that $i_0: (X_0, \|\cdot\|_{X_0}) \rightarrow (Y_0, \|\cdot\|_{Y_0}),\; x \mapsto x$ and
>   $i_1: (X_1, \|\cdot\|_{X_1}) \rightarrow (Y_1, \|\cdot\|_{Y_1}),\; x \mapsto x$  are continuous.
>
> If $T \in L(Y_0, Y_1)$ so that $T(X_0) \subseteq X_1$, define  $S: (X_0, \|\cdot\|_{X_0}) \rightarrow (X_1, \|\cdot\|_{X_1}), \;x \mapsto Tx$ and show that $S$ is continous.
>
> Any ideas how to prove it?

I was thinking about it for a moment and thought that I came up with a counterexample. Before I could post it, there was an answer showing that it is indeed true. The proof is rather short and looks very convincing. My question is therefore:

> What is wrong with my counterexample?

For a counterexample pick a Banach space $(Z, \Vert \cdot \Vert_Z)$, a discontinuous linear map $C: (Z, \Vert \cdot \Vert_Z)\rightarrow (Z, \Vert \cdot \Vert_Z)$. We define $X:=Z\oplus Z$ with the norm $\Vert (z_1, z_2)\Vert := \Vert z_1\Vert_Z +\Vert z_2\Vert_Z$. Then define two discontinuous linear maps 
$$A: (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert) \rightarrow (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert), A(z_1, z_2):= C(z_1)+z_2$$
and
$$ B: (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert) \rightarrow (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert), B(z_1, z_2):=z_1+ C(z_2). $$
Then we define two new norms on $X$. Namely, we define for $x\in X$
$$ \Vert x\Vert_A := \Vert x\Vert + \Vert Ax\Vert$$
and
$$ \Vert x\Vert_B := \Vert x \Vert + \Vert Bx\Vert.$$
Now pick 
$$(X_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{X_0})= (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_A ) = (Y_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{Y_0})$$ 
and 
$$ (X_1, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{X_1}) = (X, \Vert \cdot \Vert_B)$$
and
$$ (X, \Vert \cdot\Vert) = (Y_1, \Vert \cdot \Vert).$$
We have
$$ \Vert i_0 x\Vert_{Y_0} = \Vert x\Vert_{Y_0} =\Vert x\Vert_A = \Vert x\Vert_{X_0}$$
and
$$ \Vert i_1 x\Vert_{Y_1} = \Vert x\Vert \leq \Vert x\Vert + \Vert Bx\Vert = \Vert x\Vert_{X_1}$$
Thus,  $i_0$ and $i_1$ are continuous. Furthermore, we set
$$ T: (Y_0, \Vert \cdot\Vert_{Y_0}) \rightarrow (Y_1, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{Y_1}), x\mapsto Ax.$$
We compute 
$$\Vert T x\Vert_{Y_1} = \Vert Ax \Vert \leq \Vert x\Vert_{Y_0}$$
Hence, also $T\in L(Y_0, Y_1)$.

You claim now that the map $S: (X_0, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{X_0}) \rightarrow (X_1, \Vert \cdot \Vert_{X_1}), x\mapsto Ax$ is continuous as well. This is not true. Note that $i: Z \rightarrow X, z \mapsto (0,z)$ is continuous. If $S$ was continuous, then also the map $F = S\circ i: (Z, \Vert \cdot \Vert_Z) \rightarrow (X_1, \Vert \cdot\Vert), z \mapsto A(0, z)$ was continuous. This would imply
$$ \Vert z \Vert_Z + \Vert C(z) \Vert_Z 
= \Vert (0,z) \Vert +  \Vert B(0,z) \Vert
= \Vert (0,z) \Vert_{X_1} = \Vert A(0,z)\Vert
= \Vert F(z) \Vert \leq \Vert F \Vert_{op} \Vert z \Vert_Z $$
which tells us that $C$ is continuous, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X$ is not a Banach space with e.g. $\|\cdot\|_A$. If it were we would have that $\|\cdot\|_A$ is equivalent to the usual norm on $X$ by Banach's isomorphism theorem since it is clear that $\|x\| \leq \|x\|_A$. If this is true then there is $c$ such that $\|x\|_A = \|x\| + \|Ax\| \leq c\|x\|$ which implies that $A$ is bounded with norm at most $c-1$. Since the projection maps are continuous, this would imply that $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto C(z_1)$ is continuous which in turn implies that $C$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you. That was incredibly stupid of me...

Comment: It's easy to make mistakes like this one when trying to come up with a counterexample. I spent some time thinking about that question earlier and even posted and then deleted an incorrect counterexample with a worse error than this.